# Comparing the two consecutive rows in oracle from same table

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Comparing the two consecutive rows in oracle with first time date change from same table. In below table it should return rows 5 & 6, 8 & 9

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F6WN.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytics functions: `lag()` (resp. `lead()`) lets you retrieve the value of `date` on the previous row (res. next row), which you can then compare to the value on the current row in an outer query:

```
select pk, name, date
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        lag(date)  over(order by pk) lag_date,
        lead(date) over(order by pk) lead_date  
    from mytable t
) t
where lag_date <> date or lead_date <> date
```

Note: this assumes that column `pk` can be used to order the records (as shown in your sample data).

Comment: This looks good only problem is it returns row number 5 and 8. Not the next record when its changed. I was looking to have rows 5 & 6, 8 & 9

Comment: @Sam: my bad. Just fixed

Comment: Thanks. Nice example of lag and lead. Appreciate it.